# VUEX mutate array data each request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I have some data from an API that I am storing in `VUEX` and then displaying in the UI. On initial page load there is a request that pulls in the initial data and displays. All works well. My issues is When I now submit a form input for another request using an event handler I am just pushing to the array and it is adding to the array (which makes sense) and creates another instance below the current data which I do not want. Is there a way to actually CHANGE / MUTATE the current data that is in the array and update the UI with the new values?

STORE

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

    export default createStore({
      state: {
        ipData: [],
        currentIP: '',
      },
      mutations: {
        SET_CURRENT_IP(state, currentIP) {
          state.currentIP = currentIP;
        },
        SET_IP_DATA(state, ipData) {
          state.ipData.push(ipData);
        },
      },
    });
```

FORM SUBMIT

```
 methods: {
    async submitForm() {
      const isFormValid = await this.v$.$validate();
      if (!isFormValid) return;

      axios
        .get(`${this.url}${this.getIP}`, {
          headers,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.$store.commit('SET_IP_DATA', response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response);
        });
    },
  },
```

VUEX OBJECT:

```
ipData:Array[1]
0:Object
as:Object
domains:Array[5]
ip:"8.8.8.8"
isp:"Google LLC"
location:Object
city:"Mountain View"
country:"US"
geonameId:5375480
lat:37.38605
lng:-122.08385
postalCode:"94035"
region:"California"
timezone:"-07:00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ipData` is array of object, you can create another mutation for updating your array (use id or some other identifier to match right object):

```
UPDATE_IP_DATA(state, payload) {
  state.ipData = [
   ...state.ipData.map((item) =>
      item.id !== payload.id
        ? item
        : {
          ...item,
          ...payload,
        }
     ),
  ];
}
```

Comment: it is indeed an object array. Maybe dumb question but where would you get the indentifier to match?

Comment: @hendy0817 hey mate, identifier is one property in your object, that uniquely identifies that object. If you show me an example of your object in ipData array , I will try to tell you which one to use

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate the help! I added the object from vuex, clears things up for me for the future :)

Comment: I guess `ip:"8.8.8.8"` is unique for every object you can use that, so instead `item.id !== payload.id` you can match ip `item.ip !== payload.ip`